# Proof that the dual space $(C[0,1])^*$ is not separable.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, separable-spaces

> Let $X=C[0,1]$ equipped with the maximum norm and define a bounded linear functional $\phi_x(f)=f(x)$ for $x\in [0,1]$. I want to show that $X^*$ is not separable.

There was a hint in this exercise, which told me to compute $\|\phi_x-\phi_y\|$ for $x\neq y$. I was able to show that $\|\phi_x-\phi_y\|=2$ for $x\neq y$ in $[0,1]$. Now I assumed that $X^*$ is separable. I.e that there exists a countable dense subset, say $S\subset X^*$ countable such that $\overline{S}=X^*$. Since for all $x\in [0,1]$ $\phi_x\in X^*$ we know that there exists a sequence $(f_{x,n})_n$ such that $$f_{x,n}\stackrel{n\rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow}  \phi_x$$

But here I don't now how to continue, I think I should get a contradiction with $\|\phi_x-\phi_y\|=2$. I therefore thought that $$2=\|\phi_x-\phi_y\|\le \|\phi_x-f_{x,n}\|+\|f_{x,n}-f_{y,n}\|+\|f_{y,n}-\phi_y\|$$ the problem here is that I know that $ \|\phi_x-f_{x,n}\|\rightarrow 0$ and $\|f_{y,n}-\phi_y\|\rightarrow 0$ but I have no control on the middle term. Therefore this does not work. Is there another way to get a contradiction?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/224940/showing-that-dual-space-of-c0-1-is-not-separable

Comment: @温泽海 but there they do not use my $\phi_x$ as I understood it and I want to do it in this way. Or maybe I misunderstand this other answer, but for me it is not clear at the moment

Comment: You have obtained a continuum elements in $X^*$ such that the distance between two different elements is equal $2.$ Consider the open unit ball  $B_x$ around each element. The balls are mutually disjoint. There are uncountably many of them. Hence for every countable set  $S,$ there is a ball $B_x$ such that $B_x\cap S=\emptyset.$

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

Let $S\subseteq (C[0,1])^*$ be a dense subset.

Let $\varpi\colon [0,1]\to S$ be given as follows:

Because $S$ is dense, for each $r\in[0,1]$ there is a $s\in S$ such that $\|\phi_r-s\|<1$. Now let $\varpi(r)$ be such an $s$ (using axiom of choice).

Now we can show that $\varpi$ is injective: If $\varpi(a)=\varpi(b)$, then $\|\phi_a-\phi_b\|\leq\|\phi_a-\varpi(a)\|+\|\phi_b-\varpi(b)\|<1+1=2$ which implies $a=b$ because otherwise $\|\phi_a-\phi_b\|=2$.

Hence $S$ is uncountable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Shouldn't it be "because otherwise $\|\phi_a-\phi_b\|<2$"?

Comment: It depends: If "otherwise" = "in the case of $a\neq b$ one would have" then it would be "because otherwise $\| \phi_a-\phi_b\|<2$".